# Modify code to accept any real numbers(integer or float)

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, integer

I can figure out how to make this code accept float points as well as integers.

What this code does is it: Accepts an unlimited amount of user inputs, must as non-negative integers.  when a blank line is detected the input ends.

The code; prints the list in ascending order. prints a total of all the numbers and then prints the average number.

code:

```
nums = []
response = " "
total = 0

print("Type a positive integer: ")

while response != "":
    response = input()
    if response.isnumeric():
        nums.append(int(response))
        print("Next number: ")

    elif response == '':
        break    
    else:
        print("Error, you have to type a non-negative integer.")

nums.sort()

for item in nums:
    total = total + item
if nums != []:
    print("The numbers in order: ",nums)    
    print("Total number: ",total)
    print("The average is",sum(nums) / len(nums))
else:
    print("There are no numbers in the list")
```

Comment: What is the question, if you can figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
nums.append(int(response))
```

is casting your string input to integerss. Simply change it to:

```
nums.append(float(response))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to take integers **as well as** floats then you need to remove the cast entirely:

```
nums.append(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append integers as `int` and floats as `float`, you can use :

```
nums.append(float(response) if "." in number else int(response))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` class has an `.is_integer()` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```py
buf = float(response)
if buf.is_integer():
    buf = int(buf)
nums.append(buf)
```